# Can a voided contract be amended?

Tags: contract-law

The 1st contract was signed by both parties but the services were misrepresented to Party A. This made the contract void. Party A attempted to back out of the contract, but Party B amended the contract and Party A signed the amended contract. Both parties received consideration in the amended contract. Is the amended contract, that is based on the first voided contract, valid and enforceable?

If it is valid and enforceable:
What if Party A felt pressured (due to financial reasons/limitations) to sign the amended contact? Is it enforceable?

Answer (score 1):

> Can a voided contract be amended?

Strictly speaking, what you refer to as *amended contract* is actually a new contract. The term of *amended* might have a connotation that some changes were made to a former contract *while* it still was in force (or *prior* thereto).

> Is the amended contract, that is based on the first voided contract, valid and enforceable?

Yes, unless the clauses or misrepresentation of the new contract renders it unenforceable, regardless of how similar to the voided contract it looks. The new contract became binding and enforceable as soon as party A signed it.

The mere existence of similarities between the voided contract and the new one are mostly irrelevant for determining the enforceability of the new contract.

You did not specify what kind of misrepresentations induced party A to sign the initial contract. It is noteworthy that if certain types of misrepresentations persist in the new contract, party A might have forfeited his entitlement to void or get out of the new contract. That would qualify as what the [*Restatement (Second) of Contracts* at § 152-154](https://www.nylitigationfirm.com/files/restat.pdf) calls "*A Party Bear[ing] the Risk of a Mistake*".

> What if Party A felt pressured (due to financial reasons/limitations) to sign the amended contact? Is it enforceable?

A contract is void if duress or coercion by one of the parties prompted the other(s) to accept that contract. If the coercion is not reasonably traceable to party B, then party A's external circumstances usually are not cognizable as grounds for voiding the contract.

Comment: The Restatement (Second) of Contracts is available [here](https://www.fbcoverup.com/docs/library/1981-Restatement-Second-of-Contracts-1981.pdf), now that the law firm from the link in this answer removed that resource and posted some useless "overview of contract law" instead.